# Irish birth in Cork 1835

Tags: census-records, death-records, ireland, merchant-navy

My 3x great grandfather was born in Mallow, Cork in 1835 and became a seaman. He apprenticed in Padstow, Cornwall until 1850 and then worked on ships mostly out of Liverpool where he had a family and died in 1898. I have copies of his related UK documents (marriage, baptism of children and deaths and death of children) and have found 1881 and 1891 census records. I cannot locate the family in 1871 nor can I find a record of the first marriage (noted as widower in second marriage certificate and two eldest children too close in age to second wife for her to be their mother). I’ve searched in vain for Irish records.

How might I identify the first wife?

How might I find out if the 3x grandfather had siblings?

Comment: Do you have the places of birth for the two eldest children (perhaps from the census records)?

Comment: Unless there is a privacy reason to do otherwise I think you should include the name of your ancestor.

Comment: If he was apprenticed in Cornwall until the age of 15, then worked around Liverpool, what makes you think that the first marriage was in Ireland?

Comment: I think you are asking two distinct questions about the same man and should split this one question into two separate questions.